# Optimal values for "keep alive" (SearchScroll API ) and "batch size" for bulk API ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to reindex data in my ES index (150 million documents). I am going to use search and scroll API to get the data from old index (I cannot use reindex API because we have old ES version) and use bulk API to copy it on the new index.
My questions are

- What is the most optimised values I should put for “keep alive” time of scroll search - 1, 2 or 5 minutes?
- What is the best value for batch size for bulk request - 1000 elements or more?
- How many documents I should copy in one bulk requests?

*UPDATE:
I have 4 shards in the index